# CMD Batch script to sort files

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, ftp

I have an application which saves files to a FTP folder that I sync to my PC which contains multiple JPG and MP4 files, named in the following format:

```
ARC20170510151547.jpg
ARC20170510151549.mp4
```

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Copy the files from my FTP to my PC
2. Sort the files into folders based on the day they were created
3. Delete files from the FTP older than 14 days
4. Delete files from the PC older than 1 month

Using WinSCP to connect to FTP with the following code, I am able to download all the files to my local drive:

```
"c:\program files (x86)\winscp\winscp.com" /ini=nul /command ^
    "open ftp://[username]:[password]@[ipaddress]/" ^
    "synchronize local f:\[localpath]\ /[remotepath]/ " ^
"exit"
```

Then I need to sort the files. Here is where I am stuck. I'm think I know the commands but I am unsure how to use the 'tokens' and 'delims' to get it to work how I want.

```
@echo
for %%a in (*.*) do (
   echo processing "%%a"
      for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ("%%~nxa") do (
         md "%%b-%%c" 2>nul
         move "%%a" "%%b-%%c" >nul
      )
)
pause
```

As I know the filename format isn't going to change, one thing I have considered is adding some special characters to the filename, maybe using the 'ren' command. I could then use those special characters as search delims but, again, I'm struggling how to best proceed.

Removing local files older than 30 days is easy using the following script

```
forfiles -p "f:\[localpath]" -s -m *.* -d <number of days> -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

However, the WinSCP 'RM' command I am using doesn't appear to be working. It returns an error "no file matching '*<14D' found"

```
"rm /[filepath]/*<14D" ^
```

Any help, advice and guidance would be very gratefully received!

Comment: `rm /[filepath]/*<14D` is perfectly correct and works (if you are using recent version of WinSCP) - if not, show us a log file - Are you sure the files on FTP server have correct timestamps?

Comment: Point 2. is ambiguous. The date created doesn't necessarily match the date in the file name.  Sort means move? Also the folder structure is unclear. P4 has to dive into the structure or delete from transfer folder?

Comment: Hi there, thank you for responding. Sorry, for the confusion!So yes, the top level folder would be the year, the next would be the month, the following would be the day which would have the corresponding files in. And you are correct, the sort is on the file name, it just so happens that the filename is generated based on the creation date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no delimiter between the date elements you need substrings,
substrings do only work with normal variables and in a (code block) you need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

<s>It's unclear if you want folders with year-month or month-day, select the proper part in the batch and comment/uncomment the Rem:</s>
With extensions enabled md can create the structure `YY-MM\DD`in one step.
So you can move directly to that folder.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (ARC*.*) do (
   echo processing "%%a"
   Set File=%%~nA
   Set YY=!File:~3,4!
   Set MM=!File:~7,2!
   Set DD=!File:~9,2!
   Rem YY-MM\DD
   md "!YY!-!MM!\!DD!" 2>nul
   move "%%a" "!YY!-!MM!\!DD!" >nul
)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit, this works perfectly! Thank you very much for your assistance!

I'm going to take another look at the issue with the "rm" command when using WinSCP and send the log files as requested.

Comment: To honour a helpful answer you might vote up and/or check mark the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@LotPings! Thank you for the script. This does almost what I want it to do. I have modified the script as below which moves the files into folders based on the Day.

So, each day, maybe 100 - 200 files are generated. So I do not mind having a folder for each day. Once the files are moved into their respective "Day" folder, what I'd then like to do is create a SubFolder "!YY!-!MM!" and then move the "!DD!" Folders into the "!YY!-!MM!" folder.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%a in (ARC*.*) do (
    echo processing "%%a"
    Set File=%%~a
    Set YY=!File:~3,4!
    Set MM=!File:~7,2!
    Set DD=!File:~9,2!
    md "!DD!" 2>nul
    md "!YY!-!MM!" 2>nul
    move "%%a" "!DD!" >nul
 )
 pause
```